# How to show modal newsletter popup only once in per session?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

This is my code for using modal popup only once in per session,My problem is, everytime I visit the homepage, the div will show up. Instead I would like to show the div only once per session. I've tried to fix it with cookies but it didn't work.

```
<script>
    if (!Cookies.get('popup')) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#myModal').modal();
        }, 600);
    }
    $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
        // bootstrap modal callback function
        // set cookie
        Cookies.set('popup', 'valid', { expires: 3, path: "/" }); // need to set the path to fix a FF bug
    })
</script>
```

Comment: use session storage to store a flag as to whether the modal has shown. Initially set the flag to false and then on the modal showing set it to true and therefore you can check if the flag is true and if so - then don't show the modal

Answer (score 0):

Set a cookie.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
if ($.cookie('noShowWelcome')) $('.yourDivClass').hide();
else {
    $("#close-welcome").click(function() {
        $(".yourDivClass").fadeOut(1000);
        $.cookie('noShowWelcome', true);    
    });
  }
});
```

You need to include jQuery.cookie javascript file.

[Download jQuery.cookie](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/master/src/jquery.cookie.js)

Hope this helps :)